# Error when I export PDF file using Crytal Report C#

Tags: c#, iis-7.5

I'm getting issue when i export pdf file

```
This field name is not known.
Details: errorKind
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportOptions options)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportOptions options, HttpResponse response, Boolean asAttachment, String attachmentName)
   at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType formatType, HttpResponse response, Boolean asAttachment, String attachmentName)
   at b2b.modules.tracuu.ctlAcStmt.ExportRpt(String rptType)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

This field name is not known.
Details: errorKind
Error in File rpt_t24stmt {459D6546-D8C8-4D21-AB11-607E228165A2}.rpt:
Error in formula  : 
'ToNumber (Replace ({},",", ""))'
This field name is not known.
Details: errorKind
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext)
   at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
```

After I reset pool IIS application , I still export pdf file. Also this error come then.

Please help me some advices to fix this issue...
Thanks all.

Comment: Could you please tell me if your application is working well in the develop environment? If this is working well. I suggest you could check the IIS web.config's connection string to make sure your database contains the right the field.

Comment: Thanks you,i checked the rootcause my problem